# JavaDoc from External Library (.AAR)

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, javadoc

I'm using Android Studio 0.8.13 on Windows 7.

I had created an external library (.AAR file) form project that i want to reuse.
All classes and methods wrote with javadoc description.

The problem is when i migrate this external library with another project I can use the library objects but it will not show the javadoc of the external library (When pressing CTRL +Q).

I searched any place on the net to figure it out, without result, so any help will be appreciate.

Best Regards,

Moshik.

Answer (score 0):

In past works that code:

```
/* ask gradle for source code and javadocs downloads */
idea {
  module {
    downloadSources = true
    downloadJavadoc = true
  }
}
```

add this on the same level as `android{...}` section declared

Comment: Error:(12, 0) No such property: downloadJavadoc for class: com.android.build.gradle.AppExtension_Decorated

Comment: You forget to include/attach/use gradle plugin... provided properties works 100%

Comment: included the plugin 'idea' but does not seem to work on Android Studio